# python newbie question: converting code to classes

Tags: python, class, csv

i have this code:

```
import csv
import collections

def do_work():
      (data,counter)=get_file('thefile.csv')
      b=samples_subset1(data, counter,'/pythonwork/samples_subset3.csv',500)
      return

def get_file(start_file):

        with open(start_file, 'rb') as f:
            data = list(csv.reader(f))
            counter = collections.defaultdict(int)

            for row in data:
              counter[row[10]] += 1
            return (data,counter)

def samples_subset1(data,counter,output_file,sample_cutoff):

      with open(output_file, 'wb') as outfile:
          writer = csv.writer(outfile)
          b_counter=0
          b=[]
          for row in data:
              if counter[row[10]] >= sample_cutoff:
                 b.append(row) 
                 writer.writerow(row)
                 b_counter+=1
      return (b)
```

i recently started learning python, and would like to start off with good habits. therefore, i was wondering if you can help me get started to turn this code into classes. i dont know where to start.

Comment: this guy suggested it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354218/python-proper-usage-of-global-variable/3354537#3354537

Comment: While there are a lot of nitpicky style suggestions I could make, I agree that a class isn't really necessary for a program this small.

Comment: tiptych, can you please make those suggestions, i am very happy to hear them

Comment: Don't bother. Your code looks fine. That guy is right that classes are better than global variables. But there is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: @Jason: of course there is nothing wrong with this code it was written by SO! have a peak at the OP's history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my comment on the original post, I don't think a class is necessary here. Still, if other Python programmers will ever read this, I'd suggest getting it inline with PEP8, the Python style guide. Here's a quick rewrite:

```
import csv
import collections

def do_work():
    data, counter = get_file('thefile.csv')
    b = samples_subset1(data, counter, '/pythonwork/samples_subset3.csv', 500)

def get_file(start_file):
    with open(start_file, 'rb') as f:
        counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
        data = list(csv.reader(f))

        for row in data:
            counter[row[10]] += 1

    return (data, counter)

def samples_subset1(data, counter, output_file, sample_cutoff):
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        b = []
        for row in data:
            if counter[row[10]] >= sample_cutoff:
                b.append(row) 
                writer.writerow(row)

    return b
```

Notes:

1. No one uses more than 4 spaces to
   indent ever. Use 2 - 4. And all
   your levels of indentation should
   match.
2. Use a single space after the commas between arguments
   to functions ("F(a, b, c)" not
   "F(a,b,c)")
3. Naked return statements at the end of a function
   are meaningless. Functions without
   return statements implicitly return
   `None`
4. Single space around all
   operators (a = 1, not a=1)
5. Do not
   wrap single values in parentheses.
   It looks like a tuple, but it isn't.
6. b_counter wasn't used at all, so I
   removed it.
7. csv.reader returns an iterator, which you are casting to a list. That's usually a bad idea because it forces Python to load the entire file into memory at once, whereas the iterator will just return each line as needed. Understanding iterators is absolutely essential to writing efficient Python code. I've left `data` in for now, but you could rewrite to use an iterator everywhere you're using `data`, which is a list.

Comment: this part does not work for me: for row in csv.reader(f):, it returns nothing

Comment: My fault - didn't notice you were returning the `data` variable. That changes things.

Comment: @l__: to get rid of the list cast, just do `data = csv.reader(f)`. Then, as well as passing `data` to `samples_subset1`, pass `f` and call `f.seek(0)` before iterating through it again. That alone should be a huge performance increase.

Comment: katriealex, can u give me an example of how i would pass f.seek(0) ??

Comment: File "C:\pythonwork\readthefile072810.py", line 6, in do_work
    b=samples_subset1(data,counter,'/pythonwork/samples_subset4.csv',500,f)
  File "C:\pythonwork\readthefile072810.py", line 23, in samples_subset1
    f.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: what do i do with f in samples_subset1

Comment: Oh, I see. Basically, what you did before was to read the file into a list in memory and then close the file. You don't have to read it all in at once -- but then, you can't close the file. The `with` statement automagically closes f when it terminates, which in this case is bad. I'll add a new post with a rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure what you want to turn into a class. Do you know what a class is? You want to make a class to represent some type of *thing*. If I understand your code correctly, you want to filter a CSV to show only those rows whose `row[ 10 ]` is shared by at least `sample_cutoff` other rows. Surely you could do that with an Excel filter much more easily than by reading through the file in Python?

What the guy in the other thread suggested is true, but not really applicable to your situation. You used a lot of global variables unnecessarily: if they'd been necessary to the code you should have put everything into a class and made them attributes, but as you didn't need them in the first place, there's no point in making a class.

Some tips on your code:

- Don't cast the file to a list. That makes Python read the whole thing into memory at once, which is bad if you have a big file. Instead, simply iterate through the file *itself*: `for row in csv.reader(f):` Then, when you want to go through the file a second time, just do `f.seek(0)` to return to the top and start again.
- Don't put `return` at the end of every function; that's just unnecessary. You don't need parentheses, either: `return spam` is fine.

#### Rewrite

```
import csv
import collections

def do_work():
    with open( 'thefile.csv' ) as f:
        # Open the file and count the rows.
        data, counter = get_file(f)
        
        # Go back to the start of the file.
        f.seek(0)

        # Filter to only common rows.
        b = samples_subset1(data, counter, 
            '/pythonwork/samples_subset3.csv', 500)
   
     return b

def get_file(f):
    counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
    data = csv.reader(f)
    
    for row in data:
        counter[row[10]] += 1

    return data, counter

def samples_subset1(data, counter, output_file, sample_cutoff):
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        b = []
        for row in data:
            if counter[row[10]] >= sample_cutoff:
                b.append(row) 
                writer.writerow(row)

    return b
```

Comment: thank you. excel is not the right tool for this job. vba is a piece of garbage compared to python :)

Comment: Agree 100%. What you've done so far coming from your original code is to create functions that nicely react only to what's given to them as inputs, and have an effect only to what they're going to return as values. This, in itself, is a Good Thing ;) Making this a class reintroduces the danger of manipulating variables in a less obvious fashion than you're doing now, while the complexity of the state isn't high enough that you'd benefit at the same time.

Comment: Are you sure Excel isn't the right tool for the job? I don't mean that you should write a macro in VBA (ugh!!!)! You're doing data filtering: you want to show row n only if `=COUNTIF(K1:K.,Kn)>=sample_cutoff`. That's built into Excel.

Comment: im sure it is, as ive had lots of experience with it

Comment: Did you actually read what I wrote? I'll tell you: Excel does this, and it does it very simply. Step 1: make a new column in your CSV, with formula `=COUNTIF(K1:K.,Kn)>=sample_cutoff`. Step 2: Data->AutoFilter. Step 3: In the top of the new column, click the drop-down menu button and select TRUE. You're done, no Python involved.

Comment: yes you are right if it were just that function then excel would be my choice, but there are a bunch of other steps i need ot do after this

Comment: btw my file is 100megs, it would be difficult to do anything with in excel with a file that big without crashing my computer

Comment: OK, sorry. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: please see comments to your suggestions above this questino