# Help Defining Global Names

Tags: python, function-calls

My Code:

```
def A():
    a = 'A'

    print a

    return

def B():

    print a + ' in B'

    return
```

When B() is entered into the interpeter I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<module1>", line 9, in B
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

How should I go about defining a? I want the end result to be 'A in B', when B() is entered into the interpreter

edit:
I'd like to keep the definition of a within A() if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm pretty new to Python and you might want to take thes following with a grain of salt, but did you consider to have your variable a and the functions A() and B() as members of a class?

```
class myClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ''

    def A(self):
        self.a = 'A'
        print self.a

    def B(self):
        print self.a + ' in B'


def main():
    stuff = myClass()
    stuff.A()
    stuff.B()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When i save the code above in a file and run it, it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
def A():
    global a
    a = 'A'
    print a

def B():
    global a
    print a + ' in B'

A()
B()
```

this prints:

```
A
A in B
```

BTW: You never need a plain "return" at the end of a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'A'    
def B():    
    print a + ' in B'
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the definition of a within A() if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `global` keyword:

```
def A():
    global a
    a = 'A'

def B():
    global a
    # ...
```

However, using global variables is generally a *bad idea* - are you sure there's not a better way to do what you want to do?

Comment: For some reason this isn't working, I get the same name error.

Answer (score 0):

check out my answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354218/python-proper-usage-of-global-variable/3354342#3354342). Basically:

Create a new module containing only global data (in your case let's say `myGlobals.py`):

```
# create an instance of some data you want to share across modules
a=0
```

and then each file you want to have access to this data can do so in this fashion:

```
import myGlobals

myGlobals.a = 'something'
```

so in your case:

```
import myGlobals

def A():
    myGlobals.a = 'A'
    print myGlobals.a

def B():
    print myGlobals.a + ' in B'
```

Answer (score -1):

Just type like this, no need to create fuction or class :

```
global a

a = 'A'

print a 

print a + ' in B'
```