# Global name in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find out whether two numbers **N1** and **N2** are the permutations of the same digits. For example `123` and `321` are permutations of the same digits, where as `234` and `123` are not. I have used Python to solve the problem of which I am not an expert.
I am using `IDLE Python GUI` on `Windows 7`. The specifications are `Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`.

The Python code is shown below,

```
def k(n, m):
    s1 = n
    s2 = m
    k = 0
    fl = 0
    while k < 10 :
        arr1[k] = 0
        arr2[k] = 0
        k = k + 1
    while s1 > 0 :
        t = s1 % 10
        arr1[t] = 1
        t = s2 % 10
        arr2[t] = 1
        s1 = s1 / 10
        s2 = s2 / 10
    k = 0
    while k < 10 :
        if arr1[k] != arr2[k]:
            fl = 1
        k = k + 1
    return fl
```

I saved the file as `k.py` and imported using the following command `import k`. But when I tried to execute the code as `k.k(123, 321)` I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    k.k(123,321)
  File "k.py", line 7, in k
    global arr2
NameError: global name 'arr1' is not defined
```

I tried to declare the arrays as follows,

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
```

I also tried,

```
global arr1 = []
global arr2 = []
```

and

```
global arr1
global arr2
```

But I am still getting the same error. What is wrong with my code?

I have checked the following answers in **SO** but I couldn't solve my problem.

[Help Defining Global Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595690/help-defining-global-names)

[Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

**What I believed was that in Python you don't have to declare any variables, instead you can simply use them. Am I wrong about this assumption?**

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Might want to consider `sorted(str(n)) == sorted(str(m))` which is a bit easier to grok

Comment: @Jon Clements: Thanks for the simple solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do anything with global values here. Everything should be contained within the function.

The problem is simply that you don't define `arr1` or `arr2` before you try appending to them. You need to define them *in that function*, along with `s1`, `s2`, `k` and `fl`.

**Edit** I should add that your code is extremely unPythonic. All these while loops with incrementing counters should be replaced with for loops: `for k in range(10)` etc. But the first loop isn't even necessary - you should have `arr1 = [0] * 10` and the same for `arr2`.

Comment: +1. How can I define an array? I tried arr1 = [] and arr2 = [].

Comment: And you did this before you called the function?

Comment: @DDD: The question is: What is `arr1`? If you define it as an empty list, you can't use `arr1[k] = 0` because there is no element at position `k`.

Comment: @Matthias while true, that's not the source of OP's error. DDD, are you sure you did that at the start of that function along with your other definitions? Please update your code to show what you did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the arrays in the functions. And then append to it. `arr1 = []` defines an empty array.

```
arr1[k] = 2
```

tries to change the value at index `k`.
So either you should initialise it to a certain size or append to the empty array (using the `append` function).

Also, if you want to access the arrays from outside the function, you might want to return the arrays from the function

Comment: +1. But my idea was to use the index to check the presence of digits from 0 to 9.

Comment: Isn't your first loop an initialisation to 0? use arr1.append(0) instead of the indexing after having created the array as arr1 = []. Or replace the loop by arr1 = [0]*10, which creates an empty array of 10 zeroes.